# How to achieve an RTC alarm more than one month?

Tags: timer, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, real-time-clock

For my project I'm using an [RV-8564-C2](http://www.golledge.com/pdf/products/rtcs/RV8564C2_App_Man.pdf) RTC module. In the datasheet I see that alarm registers up to a month. How do I work it out if I want an alarm after for example 40 days or 2 months?

Comment: It does not look like it exists, do you mean [this](http://www.golledge.com/pdf/products/rtcs/rv8564c2.pdf)? Maybe you should give a link to the datasheet

Comment: http://www.golledge.com/pdf/products/rtcs/RV8564C2_App_Man.pdf

Comment: @Gandhi : If your question is inaccurate (you had the wrong part number), fix the question rather than adding a comment.  I have done that for you.

Comment: Three of your four tags bear no relationship to your question.  Most STM32 parts include an RTC; why would you choose to use an external module when you could just add a 32768Hz crystal to your microcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of the datasheet is that you cannot set an alarm for more than a month in advance.  You can set an alarm for a specific day of the month (or day of the week) and a specific time of day, but not a specific month.  If want to set an alarm for a specific month then I guess you'll have to check for the month in software.  For example, set the day of the month alarm so that the RTC alarms every month on the desired day and time.  Then the software handler for the alarm should check the month.  If the software handler determines that it is not the correct month yet then it should ignore the alarm (or, if necessary, reset RTC alarm so that it occurs again next month).  If it is the correct month then the software handler should promote the alarm to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The device **RV-8564-C2** only supports maximum of *5 bits number of days* for an alarm.

The device you're are working with only supports 8 bit timer. However, if you choose one with **16 bit timer** (e.g. RV-3029-C2) you could use the timer to be able to set an alarm approx **45 days** in the future.